# context is fragment is always false

Tags: android

I want to show some common snackbar by context.
When the context is Activity, Fragment or DialogFragment, I want to handle by them.
So I wrote codes like below, but it doesn't work at Fragment or DialogFragment.
I can only check that the context is activty.
I don't understand why context is fragment is not working.

```
fun Context.showSnackBar(text: String) {
    when(this) {
        is Fragment,  // not working
        is DialogFragment -> { // not working
            showSnackBar(text)
        }
        is Activity -> {
            showSnackBar(text)
        }
    }
}
```

usecase updated

```
1. RootApplication.context.showSnackBar()

2. passed paramter context -> fun foo(context: Context){context.showSnackBar()}

3. binding View's context -> binding.text.context.showSnackBar()
```

Comment: Please include the code that calls this function as well. In general, `Fragments` may not own a context unless they are attached to an activity. Maybe that's the issue here

Comment: A `Fragment` is not a `Context`, you can either use `requireContext()` or `requireActivity()` to access the host context once the Fragment is attached to its host.

Comment: thanks for your answers. I updated three usecases I want.

Comment: Always use requireContext() and requireActivity()